# Separating a string in Excel VBA

Tags: regex, vba, csv, excel

I have a series (thousands and thousands) of call record that I'm trying to create a spreadsheet of. They're all in a text file. The format looks like this:

```
12/ 13/ 05 Syracuse, NY 10: 22 AM 111- 111- 1111 2 $ - $ - $ -
12/ 13/ 05 New York, NY 10: 28 AM 111- 111- 1111 (F) 2 $ - $ - $ -
12/ 13/ 05 Orlando, FL 10: 48 AM 111- 111- 1111 (F) 4 $ - $ - $ -

3/ 9/ 09 Internal 4: 51 PM 111- 111- 1111 (E) 23 $ - $ - $ -
10/ 14/ 11 Colorado Site 8: 12 AM 111- 111- 1111 14 $ - $ - $ -
1/ 3/ 12 Dept 27 3: 16 PM 111- 111- 1111 (F) 93 $ - $ - $ -

11/ 12/ 12 Internal 3: 13 PM 18765 (E) 16 $ - $ - $ -
11/ 14/ 12 Internal 11: 43 AM John Doe 3 $ - $ - $ -
```

Month/ day/ year/ city called, STATE HH: MM APM 123- 456 7890 OptionalCode $Charge $Tax $Total

This is, minus details, directly from the file. No quotes around strings, no tabs. I tried to use text to columns, but some cities do have space and others don't.

Anyone want to point me in the right direction? RegEx maybe (Which I've heard of but never used)? Something else?

**Update:**
Thanks for the early feedback. The line are actual data from my file, though I stripped city and phone numbers. I've updated with the city information to show variance there. To the best I can see, none of the city names have a comma, but I'm dealing with close to 120,000 lines total and, obviously, haven't checked them all.

The city won't always, obviously, have a space - Syracuse above doesnt, New York, however, does. The month and date, too, aren't always 2 digits - which also throws off checks for length. I can read to first, then second forward slash, though - those are fixed after date and month values.

And the bracketed code doesn't always appear... sometimes it's there, sometimes not, though they do appear to only ever be one letter when they arrive.

I hope this clears a few things up. This would have been far easier if it was stored correctly in the first place. Sigh.

**Updates 2,3 & 4** Added a few lines from call log changes per Robin's request.

Comment: Any City Names have comma's in them?  If not and if the date, time and phone is fixed length, you could iterate through each line breaking it into smaller chunks :P

Comment: Could you please provide several actual lines from SCV? 2-3 will be enough.

Comment: The lines themselves above are, minus city and phone number data, actual lines from my source file. I will update to clarify a few things, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you asked for a VBA solution, but I do my call record parsing purely in a spreadsheet with formulae.

I have uploaded a workbook solution [here (version 3)](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzGv4Y7oyJDaWFZpb19pN0lWaVk/edit).

Once you have the workbook open, copy and paste the contents of your text file into cell `A2`. Then fill down the range `B2:X2` as far as necessary.

The formulae will work with any variation in length of month, day , year, city, state, time, code, charge, tax and total.

Let me know if any lines break. You can easily check for these by using the AutoFilter dropdown in the headers to select for errors/extraneous values. Append any offending lines to your question.

**Updates:**

Version 2 takes care of the situation where the City field contains a location name, and the State field is blank.

Version 3 takes care of the situation where the Phone Number field contains an extension number or name.

Comment: I'm fine with a spreadsheet approach,I can spit it out into a proper CSV this way, at least, and then I CAN deal with it in code. Thank you SO much.

I am updating with a single broken line format. Looks like things changed slightly in 2009 and not all city names then had a comma.

Comment: @ZacharyR - Do all the broken lines have ONLY one word between the date and the time?

Comment: No, actually - good catch. Most of them do... But a few starting in 2001 do switch it up to 2 words. None have more than two, though some have numbers. I'll add a few more broken lines.

Comment: @ZacharyR - New version uploaded. New link is in the answer.

Comment: To the best I can tell, this is flawless. Thank you. Take the rest of the day off.

Comment: I'm hoping, in part, that you didn't actually take the day off. This worked flawlessly for all but about 2500 lines. The only failures are when the phone number comes up with an extension or name, which seems to only be in the last few months. I've updated one of each line above.

Comment: @ZacharyR - Are all the extensions 4 or more digits long? Are all the names 3 or more characters (including spaces between two parts) long?

Comment: I see a few three digit extensions (Specifically, they're all exactly "123" if that helps). Names are always more than three characters long (Shortest I'm seeing is "J Li")

Comment: @ZacharyR - Version 3 uploaded. New link is in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work if there are no comma's in the city name.

```
Sub foo()
    thisLine = "12/ 13/ 05 City Name, ST 10: 28 AM 111- 111- 1111 (F) 2 $ - $ - $ -"
    thisDate = Mid(thisLine, 1, 10)
    thisLine = Mid(thisLine, 12)
    firstComma = InStr(1, thisLine, ",")
    City = Mid(thisLine, 1, firstComma - 1)
    thisLine = Mid(thisLine, firstComma + 2)
    State = Left(thisLine, 2)
    thisLine = Mid(thisLine, 4)
    thisTime = Left(thisLine, 9)
    thisLine = Mid(thisLine, 11)
    thisPhone = Left(thisLine, 14)
    thisLine = Mid(thisLine, 16)
    tempArray = Split(thisLine, "$")
    If UBound(tempArray) = 3 Then
    optionalCode = tempArray(0)
    charge = "$" & tempArray(1)
    tax = "$" & tempArray(2)
    Total = "$" & tempArray(3)
    Else
    ' throw an error something went wrong
    End If
End Sub
```